# jQuery .click method not firing for list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use `jQuery` to add a `click` function to a list item. I had this method working using JS and `onClick()`, however I am trying to bring the code up to date with using `jQuery`. So my list has the following structure:

```
<ul id="paginationList" class="pagination">
   <li id="1" class="page-item disabled">
      <a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a>
   </li>
   <li class="page-item">
       <a class="page-link" href="#">1</a>
   </li>
   <li id="2" class="page-item">
       <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The `jQuery` function is on the document.read function:

```
$(function () {
    $('ul.pagination li.page-item').click(function () {
        var $li = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Projects/ProjectTable/CountProjects',
            data: { searchString: $('#searchBox').val() },
            success: function(result) {
                $('#table-container').load('/Projects/ProjectTable/TestPartialView',
                    {
                        searchString: $('#searchBox').val(),
                        currentPage: page,
                        projectCount: result
                    }, function() {
                        $li.addClass('active');
                    }); 
            }
        });
    });

    getTable();
});
```

`getTable()` is being executed, however when I click on any `<li>` the method is not called. I have tried removing `ul.pagination` from the `.click` call but again that has had no impact.

What do I need to change so that the `<li>` have a `.click` method on each of them?

I have checked the console and there are no errors being reported at all.

Comment: It's working for me.  Are you sure this is the state of the DOM when that code executes?  Or are you dynamically changing the DOM somewhere?

Comment: @David I am rendering a partial view from ASP.NET Core so maybe this is causing an issue.

Comment: @CBreeze: The server-side technology isn't really relevant here.  Ultimately the question is whether or not you're dynamically modifying the DOM client-side.  For example, by making an AJAX request to get new data and render new elements.

Comment: @David I am doing that yes.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code.
it seems you never remove the "*disabled*" class, even when you add the "active" one (but maybe that is what you want), and you are not using [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) so maybe your even was binding *before* the `<li>` elements were created.

### Try this:

```js
$('.pagination').on("click", ".page-item", function(){
      console.log(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="paginationList" class="pagination">
   <li id="1" class="page-item disabled">
      <a class="page-link">Previous</a>
   </li>
   <li class="page-item">
       <a class="page-link">1</a>
   </li>
   <li id="2" class="page-item">
       <a class="page-link">Next</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### Here is the same code, written in a more understandable way (IMHO)

```
$(()=>{
    $('.pagination').on("click", ".page-item", onPaginationItemClick);

    function onPaginationItemClick(){
        var listItem = this,

            // it's nicer to assign jQuery ajax calls to a variable, so it could be aborted if needed
            CountProjects_REQ = $.ajax({
                type : 'GET',
                url  : '/Projects/ProjectTable/CountProjects',
                data : { searchString: $('#searchBox').val() }
            });

         // using the "done()" method on the jQuery XHR object. do not use "success", it is the old and aweful way
        CountProjects_REQ.done(RES => {
            $('#table-container').load('/Projects/ProjectTable/TestPartialView', {
                searchString : $('#searchBox').val(),
                currentPage  : page,
                projectCount : RES
            }, ()=>{
                listItem.classList.add('active');
            }); 
        })
    };

    // I have no idea what this part is for...I'll just leave it here
    getTable();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('ul.pagination li.page-item')` works for the `click` event:

```js
$('ul.pagination li.page-item').click(function () {
  console.log('clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="paginationList" class="pagination">
   <li id="1" class="page-item disabled">
      <a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a>
   </li>
   <li class="page-item">
       <a class="page-link" href="#">1</a>
   </li>
   <li id="2" class="page-item">
       <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If you are adding the `li` dynamically then you can better use,

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul.pagination li.page-item', function () {
  console.log('clicked');
});
```